# How can I implement an Ustream HLS stream in Chromecast?

Tags: android, ios, chromecast, google-cast

I've been trying to implement a live stream in Chromecast. With the Ustream api, I can get an HLS stream link. In the Google Cast docs, it says something about that the server the HLS is on needs CORS installed. I highly doubt Ustream would have that or would ever get that installed. Would there be another way to play the stream, or am I pretty much SOL?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not something that you would need to install; it is a set of headers that the server should add to their response. Chromecast requires that to be present; some folks use proxy servers to add such headers.

Comment: I read about that. I read something that it isn't a good way to go about it. Is that true?

Comment: That is correct, for testing purposes it is fine but for production no.

Comment: Do you think I am pretty much SOL getting this stream to work unless Ustream puts in the headers on there server?

Comment: All I can say is that Chromecast requirement is there and cannot be changed.